# How to play an audio from URL in flutter?

Tags: flutter, url, networking, audio, audio-streaming

I have tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
    AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  play() async {
    int result = await _audioPlayer.play('http://thedemos.in/mind/uploads/audio/WjYYX_Namaste2.mp3');
    if (result == 1) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = true;
      });
      print('Success');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please share the error message...

Answer (score 3):

[assets_audio_player 2.0.7+9](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player) use this music player, Where you can play music from the network as well as from assets folder. And Also you don't need to handle it in the background.

Answer (score 1):

**audioplayers: ^0.20.1**

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

```
var audio = AudioPlayer();

Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            onPressed: () {
              audio.play(
                  'http://119.226.104.170/Rsoft5140/66119514-20200506-183433-1588770273.71547.mp3');
            }),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
            onPressed: () {
              audio.pause();
            }),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
            onPressed: () {
              audio.stop();
            }),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**For audioplayers: ^5.1.0:**

```
audio.play(UrlSource('<Insert your URL here>'));
```